# Having issues writing ObservableList to XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to write the contents of my ObservableList to an XML file. However, it isn't working and all I get is an empty file that doesn't contain any of the ObservableList's members and just has this as the contents:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<observableListWrapper/>`.

This is my code for writing the ObservableList to the .XML file:

```
        BufferedWriter output = null;
        try {
            output = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("contacts.xml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // write contacts .XML to output
        JAXB.marshal(ContactsController.contacts, output);
```

As you can see I'm trying to write my `contacts` ObservableList to the file.
An object that would be added to the `contacts` ObservableList would look like this:

```
contacts.add(new Contacts("John", "Doe", "999-999-9999", "site@site.edu", "/images/default.jpg"));
```

I want to be able to export so I can save my contacts to a file, and then load them all into my ObservableList as well.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I've spent hours trying to figure this out and I'm stuck.

Comment: Are your Contact Class marked with JAXB Annotations?? How do you create your JAXB Context ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think ObservableList cannot be processed by the marshaller and you have to wrap it into a regular List.  See an example in https://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-tutorial/part5/